# How does normal C++ code apply to GUI Programming?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am a beginner at programming, so this might be a dumb question, but here it is...

I've been going through books, learning languages such as C and C++, and I have a basic understanding of the code.  Yet, is this type of code used in actual programs?  For example, I open a program on my computer, and there is a nice looking user interface on it.  When I code programs at home, my user interface is the command line.  But when I go to code a program with a GUI, the code I learn in books doesn't even apply to the GUI code.

So I guess I'm wondering - How does the code and things you learn in books apply to actual programs with a user interface?  And is the code used for console applications even used anymore?

Any guidance or help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Ian Vaughn

Comment: Yes, it is used in actual programs. Lots (actually, most) of stuff doesn't have GUI and goes behind the scenes. GUI with C++ - just google it, same language, same ideas, just different libraries for this. I.e., I never wrote any GUI in C++ and use console only. Like many people over here.

Comment: There are numerous books about GUI programming in C and C++.

Comment: Although this will probably be closed for other reasons, it's pretty much a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875686/advice-for-c-gui-programming

Comment: The language is universal and building block of everything, you can use it to build GUI library. what you probably mean is that wether function call such as cin/cout can be used for GUI programming, the answer is no, they are just function that tell the operating system to print characters in console, which is also written in C/C++.

Comment: "is the code used for console applications even used anymore?" -- Yes, very much so, especially by administrators, developers, and "power users" ... not so much by computer-as-appliance users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and yes.

GUI's are sometimes programmed in C++ (C is rarer), but it's also used for console programs. One special type of GUI's is in fact usually done in C++, and that's games. A common example of console programs is a converter program, which takes in one file and creates another. It's UI can be `./tool < InFile > OutFile`.